# Negative Exponents throwing NaN in Fortran

Tags: math, fortran

Very basic Fortran question. The following function returns a NaN and I can't seem to figure out why:

`F_diameter = 1. - (2.71828**(-1.0*((-1. / 30.)**1.4)))`

I've fed 2.71... in rather than using `exp()` but they both fail the same way. I've noticed that I only get a NaN when the fractional part (-1 / 30) is negative. Positives evaluate ok.

Thanks a lot

Comment: The problem seems to be the -1/30 ** 1.4; apparently gfortran is failing to raise a negative number to a fractional power. Not sure why.

Comment: ire_and_curses gave a good answer. Note that this should be standard behaviour with all Fortran compilers - since Fortran is statically typed, a REAL cannot change into COMPLEX when being operated upon - but rather, it raises an exception.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The problem is that you are taking a root of a negative number, which would give you a complex answer. This is more obvious if you imagine e.g.

```
(-1) ** (3/2)
```

which is equivalent to

```
(1/sqrt(-1))**3
```

In other words, your fractional exponent can't trivially operate on a negative number.

Answer (score 0):

There is another interesting point here I learned today and I want to add to ire_and_curses answer: The fortran compiler seems to compute powers with integers with successive multiplications.
For example

```
      PROGRAM Test
      PRINT *, (-23) ** 6
      END PROGRAM
```

work fine and gives `148035889` as an answer.

But for `REAL` exponents, the compiler uses logarithms: `y**x = 10**(x * log(y))` (maybe compilers today do differently, but my book says so). Now that negative logarithms give a complex result, this does not work:

```
      PROGRAM Test
      PRINT *, (-23) ** 6.1
      END PROGRAM
```

and even gives an compiler error:

```
Error: Raising a negative REAL at (1) to a REAL power is prohibited
```

From an mathematical point of view, this problem seems also be quite interesting: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1211/non-integer-powers-of-negative-numbers

Comment: This follows from an explicit prohibition in the Fortran standard along the lines of the error message quoted. It isn't really related to implementation. `(-23)**6.0` is also not allowed.  Indeed, integer exponents are [quite special](http://stackoverflow.com/a/28908751).