# Do sum with alternating sign in argument

Tags: fortran, fortran90

I'm doing some numerical exercises in Fortran 90. When I was trying to do a sum with alternating sign in argument I noticed that (in the manner that I did it) Fortran don't know how to do that.

For example I want to do a sum over k from 1 to 10 of ((-1)^k)/2k so what I did was

```
sumk = 0
do k = 1,10
   sumk = ((-1)**k)/(2*k) + sumk
end do
```

but the output was sumk = 1. What did I do wrong?

Comment: I always get `sumk = 0`, see my answer... Is that a typo? Do you mean `(-1)^k` or `(-i)^k` (imaginary unit)?

Comment: I mean (-1)^k, typo error. Sorry

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If `k` is an integer, you are performing integer operations. These might not do what you would expect, e.g. `1/2 = 0`. Using floats this would result in `0.5`, of course, but the conversion to integers would result in `0`.

So, basically, the part you add to `sumk` would always be zero in your case, leading to `sumk=0` in the end. To prevent this, you need to take the quotient with floats:

```
  sumk = real(((-1)**k))/real(2*k) + sumk
```

Then, the result is `-0.322817445` (which I verified using Wolfram Alpha).

---

Of course, there are several ways to improve this, such as computing `(-1)**k` iteratively, or by replacing it by a modulo operation.

Comment: Is it same to do sumk = real(((-1)**k)/(2*k)) + sumk?

Comment: No, that first does the integer operation, computes the 0 and then it converts to real 0.0.

Comment: But I think that you can do something like this: `sumk = (-1)**k/(2.0*k)`. `2.0` is `real`, so `(2.0*k)` is `real`, so the whole fraction is `real`.

Answer (score 0):

My best experience in Fortran is always to declare the numbers as you want them to use in your code as you do that with your variables.
When you want to use Double use `1.0d0`, when you want to use Single use `1.0e0` and when you want to use Integer use `1`.
So in your case I would suggest something like:

```
sumk = 0.0d0
do k = 1,10
   sumk = ((-1.0d0)**dble(k))/(2.0d0*dble(k)) + sumk
end do
```

By the way, if you don't have any memory problems I would alway use double precision.

Comment: I would *never ever* do powers with floating point exponents if I could do them with integers instead. There even is a special treatment in the Standard about this!

Comment: I agree with others. Also, this is unnecessary convoluting the code if done strictly. `((-1.d0)**k)/(2*k)` is quite enough. As for whether to always use double precision, use a working precision kind constant and set it as necessary.  Codes can be much faster in single precision.

Comment: @AlexanderVogt A special exception case I mentioned [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/28908751) ;)

Comment: I agree for speeding up codes single precision might be advantegous, but not if one gets fast wrong results because of rounding errors. As in all cases, the best solution depends on the code. Of course, in the code shown above single precision is better, I agree.