# Difference between variable types for the same computation in Fortran

Tags: fortran

I am new to Fortran and I was experimenting with int and double variables. I saw that

```
when you divide for example 
integer:: a = 5
integer:: b = 2
```

the outcome is 2
However I was wondering when we use different types is there a difference of speed? Are they calculated the same way?
For example

```
double  :: a = 2.0
integer :: b = 2

1) a**b
2) a**a
3) b**a
```

Of course the outcome for all these will be the same since they turn to double. However are they calculated the same way? Is there a difference in the speed they calculated?

EDIT : I must admit I did not know that the compiler plays a role. So far I know about 3 compilers : gfortran, nagfor and ifort. Personally I have experience in just gfortran and I tried and I got the same results in all the 3 calculations. However are they calculated the same way?

Comment: In general for real `x` we know that `x**2` and `x**2.0` are not the same, but beyond that your questions depend heavily on what system, compiler, etc. you are using. If you are interested in specific rather than broad detail, please provide more information on your use case.

Comment: @francescalus ok I will update it right now!

Comment: You may also be interested in [this other question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28908369/3157076). In my answer there I mention how exponentiation is an "exception".

Answer (score 0):

Normally, when optimizations are enabled, `a**2` with a literal `2` will be changed to `a*a`. It is less likely, but not impossible, for the compiler to do such a thing for a variable integer exponent.

A completely generic exponentiation to a real exponent is implemented using logarithms. You just need the `exp(x)` function and then you can exponentiate any other number to the power of `x` if you know the logarithm of your number.

You can test the gfortran optimizations online  https://godbolt.org/z/MvGEnn

You get a call to `__powidf2()` in the first case, and calls to `pow()` in the other cases.

Those are functions from the C runtime library.

```
 double __powidf2 (double a, int b)
```

https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gccint/Soft-float-library-routines.html

```
 double pow(double x, double y);
```

https://linux.die.net/man/3/pow

The former one is a specialized function to exponentiate to an integer and is much faster, the other is for two doubles.

You can play with the optimization level and you can also make on of the numbers known.

Like this one, where the optimizer can treat it as a constant even when it is a variable:

https://godbolt.org/z/YT3KP8

However, the compiler will not do that, if the value is only known outside the subroutine.

But when you use `-fwhole-program`, the compiler is actually able the pre-compute the result from the subroutine https://godbolt.org/z/zs43jv

I hope it illustrates that the problem is actually quite complex and cannot be answered in all generality.

Comment: @jack Of curse, that is the point of introducing the specific functiin and not doing everything with pow.